# Type boolean, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found Java (Jersey)

Tags: java, rest, jersey, media-type

I am using Jersey version 1.12 and i am facing the error that is

```
A message body writer for Java class java.lang.Boolean, and Java type boolean, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found

    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:285)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1451)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1363)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1353)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:414)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

my code is

```
        @POST
        @Path("/save/{Name}/{data}")
        @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        public String saveDataMap(@QueryParam("number") String number,
        @PathParam("data") String data,
        @PathParam("Name") String appName
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParam) throws Exception{
        boolean response =false'
        try{
        // some business logic
        response =true
        }

        return response;
        }
```

After Googling this error i found that this is due to you are not specifying the content type of the data you are sending - so Jersey is not able to locate the right MessageBodyWritter to serialize

after this i added produces anotation to the method with the `MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN` but it doesn't work ,but when i changed return type of method to `String` it started working.

I simply wants to know whats problem with boolean ,why it is not working with boolean ? and how to solve this problem without changing boolean to String ?

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually code these methods like this:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/save/{Name}/{data}")
    @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response saveDataMap(@QueryParam("number") String number,
    @PathParam("data") String data,
    @PathParam("Name") String appName
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParam) throws Exception{
    boolean response =false
    try{
    // some business logic
    response =true
    }

    return Response.ok().entity(String.valueOf(response)).build();
    }
```

The only changes is that it returns a jersey HTTP response building it from a string from a boolean.

I hope it helps.

Regards,
Cris.

Comment: it still returns string but my question is why not boolean ??
the way you provided is just same as changing the method return type to string both works in the same way

Comment: My best guess will be: "Because there is no mimetype for boolean and you have to transform it to something browsers understand". But, this is my wild guess.

Comment: Mailing list diving suggests that is, indeed, the reason: https://java.net/projects/jersey/lists/users/archive/2009-08/message/34